# Return a list instead of IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following expression:

```
var a = DBContext.Summaries
 .Where(fs => fs.PersonID == id)
 .Select(s => s.ChildAccounts);
```

which returns an object with the type:

```
IQueryable<ICollection<ChildAccount>>
```

However, I need the return type to be:

```
List<ChildAccount>
```

And I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I assume there will be a ToList() in there somewhere, but in every place I've tried I've ended up with a different, incorrect return type.

Can someone suggest the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you not try putting the `.ToList()` at the end?

Comment: Yes I did, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why didn't it work for you yet you've marked it as the right answer?

Comment: Their should be a reference duplicate on how select many works some where..

Answer (score -8, accepted):

copy and paste

`a = DBContext.Summaries.Where(fs => fs.PersonID == id).Select(s => s.ChildAccounts).ToList();`

So you are get the `Summaries` with id condition  and select what you want of columns.

if you want multiple columns you can type

var a = DBContext.Summaries.Where(fs => fs.PersonID == id).Select(s => new Summaries {
ChildAccounts = s.ChildAccounts,
....
}).ToList();

Comment: Please explain your code. Why does it work the way it works? "copy and paste" is not very constructive. OP will only learn to copy and paste, nothing more.

Answer (score 8):

Call `SelectMany`, which basically concatenates multiple result lists into one, instead of `Select`, then call `ToList`.

```
var a = DBContext.Summaries
                 .Where(fs => fs.PersonID == id)
                 .SelectMany(s => s.ChildAccounts)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, that was what I needed

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = DBContext.Summaries
 .Where(fs => fs.PersonID == id)
 .SelectMany(s => s.ChildAccounts).ToList();
```

Above code should give your `List<ChildAccount>`. Here, `SelectMany` flattens queries that return lists of lists. For example, you can see [this Live fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LNyymI).

Answer (score 1):

Though `SelectMany` does the job of flattening the collection and forming a `IEnumerable<T>` out of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, but in case you need fine grain control and want to apply custom logic then use the `Aggregate` as follows:

```
var a = DBContext.Summaries
                 .Where(fs => fs.PersonID == id)
                 .Select(s => s.ChildAccounts)
                 .Aggregate(new List<ChildAccounts>(),
                            (x,y) => 
                                    {
                                      x.AddRange(y);
                                      return x;    
                                    });
```

Following are important details:

1. `new List<ChildAccounts>()` is the empty seed data for the final collection. We can even use the first element as seed data if required and start aggregation from second element onwards
2. `x,y` parameters in the Lambda is `ICollection<ChildAccounts>` which represent the consecutive elements of outer `IQueryable` and are merged in every iteration, thus replacing the Seed for data for next execution
3. You can do custom processing while merging the `List`, but otherwise on the final result, Aggregate takes a 3rd parameter `Func<TAccumulate,TResult> resultSelector`, which can be used to make changes to the final collection.
4. Since Seed Data is a `List`, then all intermediate results are `List`, since we are returning aggregated result